# In postgresql.conf, does the order of the listed parameters matter?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I'm relatively new to the DBA field and I have read the official documentation/guides on this topic, but I apologize if my question seems weird.

I have deployed PostgreSQL 12 on my AWS instance and tried to install the pgaudit extension.
In the postgresql.conf configuration file you need to add shared_preload_libraries = 'pgaudit' and restart the PostgreSQL service to apply the change.

I added shared_preload_libraries = 'pgaudit' in the very end of the config file and restarted pg_ctl, which caused the service to crash. Postgresql started operating normally once I commented out the added line.

Later I found the shared_preload_libraries parameter in that config file, it was already there, located a few blocks above, but also commented out. Once I uncommented it and set its value to 'pgaudit', my postgresql service started working normally and I managed to create an extension.

My question is: does it really matter in what order you list the parameters? Why didn't it work when I added the line in the end of the file, but worked, when the line was somewhere in the middle?

Comment: My recommendation is *not* to add parameters at the end of the file, but at the place where they are in the comment. That is not the cause of your problem though.

Answer (score 3):

If you have several times the same parameter in postgresql.conf, the last value will override the previous ones.

I normally advise keeping the `postgresql.conf` file as short as possible to prevent confusion. See [here](https://mydbanotebook.org/post/conf-files/).

My guess is that you misspelled something on the line you added. To be sure, you can look at Postgres logfiles which should tell you exactly what was wrong. (see [here](https://mydbanotebook.org/post/troubleshooting-02/) how to find your Postgres logfile.)